# Simplest way to create in-browser python repl?

Tags: browser, python, webserver, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I want to create a very minimal version of something like Jupyter Notebook where I can type python code into a browser window, run the code on the server, and print the result to the browser. (Don't worry, I'm only going to do this on my laptop, not a publicly-facing server.)

I can totally handle the browser part.

I'm guessing the back end could be a minimal flask app.

What would be the best way to run the python code interactively? Python subprocess? I know Jupyter uses pyzmq.

I'd prefer it to be an IPython shell like Jupyter, but not a requirement.

If you suggest pyzmq, since I'm not really a server-side programmer, could you please sketch out the skeleton of the part that interacts with the python kernel?

Thanks!

Feel free to suggest a better forum for this question if superuser isn't the right one.